# forward declaration problems

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I think I am having a problem with forward declarations. I think one is necessary, but I'm not sure.

Basically I have a main.cpp:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "CalculateForces.h"
#include "ParticleBox.h"

int main(void)
{
    //g++ main.cpp ParticleBox.cpp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -std=c++0x

    CalculateForces* calculate_forces= new CalculateForces();
    ParticleBox* particles_box = new ParticleBox(2000,100,100,100);

    delete calculate_forces;
    delete particles_box;

    return 0;

}
```

CalculateForces.h looks like this:

```
//CalculateForces.h
//We update the forces on each particle
class ParticleBox;
class CalculateForces
{
    public:
        CalculateForces(void);
        ~CalculateForces(void);
        int UpdateForces(ParticleBox* particlebox);
        int DiscretizeSpace(float cutoff_distance);
        int LJForce(int local_index, int remote_index, ParticleBox* particlebox);               

};
```

And finally the ParticleBox.h File looks like this:

```
//ParticleBox.h
//This is the definition of the particlebox. We manage all the particles in this
//file

//This should be changed to a template so that we can run float and double calcs properly :D
struct Particle;

class ParticleBox
{
public:
    ParticleBox(int Num_Particles, float Box_length_x_, float Box_length_y_, float Box_length_z_);
    ~ParticleBox(void);
    int set_num_particles(int Num_Particles);
    int InitialiseUniverse(int temp,float mass);
    float Boltzmann(float temperature);
    int GenerateRandomUniquePositions(int number, float max, float min, float* rand_dim_positions);

private:
    //Array to hold particles. Each particle has its own struct
    Particle** particle_list_;

    int num_particles_;
    float box_length_x_;
    float box_length_y_;
    float box_length_z_;
    float* rand_x_positions_;
    float* rand_y_positions_;
    float* rand_z_positions_;
    float cutoff_distance_;
    float sigma_;
    float epsilon_;

};

int CalculateForces::DiscretizeSpace(float cutoff_distance, ParticleBox* particlebox)
{
    ......
    return 0;

}
```

I use a forward declaration in ParticleBox.h of the Particle Struct and I can add a pointer of type Particle* to the class. This works fine.

The forward in CalculateForces.h of Class ParticleBox causes loads of compiler errors (too many to post but they start in an identical way to the below). Omitting it produces only a few errors:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
CalculateForces.h:9:20: error: ‘ParticleBox’ has not been declared
CalculateForces.h:11:50: error: ‘ParticleBox’ has not been declared
In file included from CalculateForces.cpp:3:0:
CalculateForces.h:9:20: error: ‘ParticleBox’ has not been declared
CalculateForces.h:11:50: error: ‘ParticleBox’ has not been declared
CalculateForces.cpp:12:35: error: ‘int CalculateForces::UpdateForces’ is not a static member of ‘class CalculateForces’
CalculateForces.cpp:12:35: error: ‘ParticleBox’ was not declared in this scope
CalculateForces.cpp:12:48: error: ‘particlebox’ was not declared in this scope
CalculateForces.cpp:13:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

I thought i would need the forward declaration as I try to use that type as an argument? What am i doing wrong?

Thanks and sorry for the long post

Comment: Forward class declaration is OK.  Are you using include guards?  Can you post the error when you have the forward class declaration?

Comment: No, where should they go? In which file? Thanks

Comment: Are those two header files `#include`ing each other?

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the error you described. I suppose the error is coming from some *other* code which you didn't post. Please reduce your program to a short single file that still produces the error you describe. See http://SSCCE.org for more info.

Comment: They are definitely not including each other.

Comment: Side note: in `int* a, b`, do you know what is the type of `b`? It's `int` not `int*`. Putting `*` next to the type creates the illusion that it belongs to the type name, while in reality it belongs to the variable being defined. So if you wanted both `a` and `b` to be pointers it would be: `int* a, *b;`. Now since you're putting `*` next to `b` anyway, you might as well also place the first one next to `a`, i.e. `int *a, *b;`. In short, it's easier to understand if you put `*` next to the variable rather than the type.

Comment: @Shahbaz imho this is the *only* reasonable defense for declaring pointer-types. i.e. trivial stupid sample: `typedef int *int_ptr;`. At that time `int_ptr a,b;` means what you think it does. But ultimately even that is a crutch for lazy programming. You want to pointers, *declare two pointers*, as your comment shows. I prefer seeing the asterisks myself.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I'm having a hard time understanding your comment, but it seems like it's in agreement with mine, so thanks :D

Comment: @Shahbaz it totally *is* in agreement with yours. Sorry if that was confusing. =P

Comment: @Shahbaz A much better idea would be to not define more than one symbol in each statement.

Comment: Are you defining methods of `CalculateForces` in "ParticleBox.h"? That's ... unusual.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, as @Robᵩ commented the error is indeed in another bit of un-posted code. I will answer my own question with the solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rob determined the source of the errors was in a bit of code that I did not post. There were a few errors but the biggest was that in CalculateForces.cpp I tried to access `int num_particles_;` which is of course a private member of ParticleBox.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is quite confusing because you posted the error that show up when you omit the forward declaration and you obviously have some additional errors in your code that mix with the error you asked about.

I assume that with the forward declaration, the errors change as they appear mostly in the implementation files, right? In this case the problem might be that the forward declaration is enough as long as you declare a pointer to the type, but it is not enough when you start using the pointer (dereferencing it).

If that is the case, the problem is most likely that you forgot to `#include "ParticleBox.h"` in `CalculateForces.cpp` (or some other implementation files).